# Association Rule on "Long" table in R

Tags: r, associations, arules, reformatting

I'm trying to run association model on below data ("long table"):

```
Alarm         Ticket
A               T1  
B               T1
C               T1
D               T1
B               T2
C               T2
A               T3
A               T4
B               T4
```

But I think the "arules" package can only run on "wide table".
i.e.

```
Ticket  Alarm1 Alarm2 Alarm3 Alarm4
T1        A      B      C      D  
T2        B      C
T3        A
```

(Combining all the alarms of one ticket into one row)

So is there any way I can run the association analysis on the long table or I have to do the "long to wide" table reformat?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Association rules only work on binary variables.

You can use model.matrix, but you need to feed it a data.frame

Something like:

`model.matrix( ~ alarm - 1, data = your_data)`

should create an appropriate matrix.

Run the following to see how it works:

```
alarm <- rep(c("a","b","c"),2)
ticket <- rep(c("t1","t2"),3)

df <-data.frame(cbind(alarm,ticket))
df

model.matrix(data = df, ~alarm -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer code like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(
  Alarm = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), 
  Ticket = c(rep("T1", 4), "T2", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T4")
)

> library("arules")
> trans <- as(split(df$Alarm, df$Ticket), "transactions")
> inspect(trans)
   items     transactionID
 1 {A,B,C,D} T1           
 2 {B,C}     T2           
 3 {A}       T3           
 4 {A,B}     T4
```